# User-defined function as parameter in DolphinDB Plugin

Tags: dolphindb

I'm writing a plugin for DolphinDB following [this repo](https://github.com/dolphindb/DolphinDBPlugin), and I want to pass a user-defined function, like this:

in cpp:

```
extern "C" ConstantSP funcInCpp(Heap* heap, vector<ConstantSP>& arguments);
```

in DolphinDB script:

```
loadPlugin("...")
def g(x) { return x + 1 }
funcInCpp(g)
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't have any problem. In your plugin code, please cast ConstantSP to FunctionDefSP.